# Is .NET's GzipStream compatible with Qt's zlib-based qCompress/qUncompress?

Tags: .net, qt, compression, gzip, zlib

Is .NET's GzipStream compatible with Qt's zlib-based qCompress/qUncompress? I believe they both use the deflate algorithm, so would I be able to use .NET's DeflateStream or GzipStream to read data written by Qt's qCompress, and write data readable by Qt's qUncompress without reimplementing zlib in its entirety in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it. First, qCompress() puts data size in the first 4 bytes which has nothing to do with zlib standards. You may wish to skip those bytes, but that's a dirty hack. Second, GzipStream sounds like it reads Gzip format (zlib format designed for compressing files) when qCompress() uses compress2() call which uses another zlib format designed for in-memory compression.

qCompress() and qUncompress() are designed to work with each other and nothing more. If you need compatibility with other code, use zlib directly, it is easy and portable. In fact, we are doing it in our company - the server uses Qt, the clients use .Net and Java. Works perfectly.

Comment: What implementations of zlib for .NET and Java would you recommend? I know of ZLIB.NET (http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm) but what about Java? What are the de facto standard libraries for zlib support in .NET and Java?

Comment: I use [JZlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) for Java, works fine, only flush support is somewhat retarded - you have to write something to flush (and a zero-sized byte array won't do as writing it does nothing). Don't know about .Net  as I'm not a .Net developer.

Comment: As a side-note: I found that ZLIB.NET is compatible with qCompress/qUncompress. .NET's DeflateStream and GzipStream are not. Make sure to append and strip the first 4 bytes specifying the uncompressed length when compressing and decompressing, however.

Comment: Years after, I was facing the same problem. Integrating @JakePetroules 's comment with [this article](http://george.chiramattel.com/blog/2007/09/deflatestream-block-length-does-not-match.html), I discovered why the DeflateStream was not directly compatible: the first two chars. So you can definitely use the .NET's DeflateStream, provided that you discard the first SIX bytes from the array (four with the length plus 2 with the zlib's header). Tested using QT 5.7.0 and VS2015 with .NET 4.5.2